# Automatically take screenshot of specific display in X

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, screenshot

For creating a time lapse on a system running X with two screens (actually it's one "screen" on two "displays"), how do I take a screenshot of one of the screens?

`xrandr` output is (abbreviated):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP5 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    59.94  
   [...]
DFP6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP7 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    59.94  
   [...]
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Requirements:

1. Minimal overhead
2. Desktop environment agnostic
3. Automatic
4. Screen selected by name

1, 2 and 3 mean that the tool would ideally run in the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ImageMagick's `import` can take a screenshot of Xorg's root automatically and with `-crop` only the wanted part will be used. `xrandr` provides the parameter for `crop`.

To minimize overhead, you should construct the `import` command once rather than querying using the display name each time you take a screenshot:

```
mapfile -t displays < <(xrandr | grep ' connected')
get_date='`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`'
for (( i=0; i<${#displays[@]}; i++)); do
  name=`echo ${displays[i]} | cut -d " " -f 1`
  crop=`echo ${displays[i]} | cut -d " " -f 3`
  echo import -silent -window root -crop ${crop} \"${name}-${get_date}.png\"
done
```

Explanation of the mapfile and for loop can be found in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439026/).

This will give you commands like the following:

```
import -silent -window root -crop 1920x1080+0+0 "DFP5-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.png"
import -silent -window root -crop 1920x1080+1920+0 "DFP7-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`.png"
```

which you can now use in a while loop for your timelapse (stop with `ctrl+c`).

```
while [ 1 ]; do
  import ...
  sleep 1 # for 1 second delay between screenshots
done
```

This is the only method I know. Hopefully there are ways with less overhead.